# Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, rest, certificate, x509certificate, restsharp

I have a console applicaiton in C# 4.6.2 framework that communicates to a REST service using RestSharp to pull some data which I then enter in to a database. The application passes along a certificate in order to verify my identity. Until recently this application was working great but has recently started throwing errors. This is now erroring on both my local machine and the server it normally runs on. I assume a policy or something was applied but I'm now getting an error of:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   at Feed_Exe.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Feed_Exe\Feed_Exe\Program.cs:line 106
```

There is not a whole lot to my code, but here is what I have and where it is failing

```
        string NextLink = "https://RESTServiceURL";

        var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.GET };
        var certFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\Feed_Exe\", "MyCert.pfx");
        var x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "CertPassword");
        //The above line is where it errors

        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NextLink))
        {
            var client = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = new Uri(NextLink),
                UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection()
                {
                    x509Cert
                }
            };

            var response = client.Execute(request);

            if (response.ErrorException == null)
            {
              //Here is where I process the data I got from the service
            }
        }
```

First off the certificate does exist in that path above. I also reexported that certificate and made sure to include the private key and root chain. Password to the certificate is also correct.

In the past I did not need to have the certificate installed on the machine in order to get things to function, as I'm not allowed to install certificates on the machine this normally runs on. I have tried installing it to my local machine (both local machine and current user stores) which did not help.

In researching this I have tried a few things. One thread suggested to include

```
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
        System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
```

Which did not help. I also saw a suggestion of:

```
        var x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "CertPassword.", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
```

which also did not help. I have also seen some suggestions of altering some IIS settings which I can do locally, but not on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Is the file possibly a symbolic link?  You can try `byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(certFile); X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(data, "CertPassword");`, which separates the I/O operation and the certificate part.

Comment: fstam - I noted above that it failed on the 'var x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "CertPassword");' line.

Comment: bartonjs - that actually worked for me to get it running locally. Not sure why the way I had it didn't work, but appears to be now. Now its a matter of seeing if that solves it on the server. Thanks!